# How can applications running in AWS know their environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have applications of different kinds running on different types of AWS hosts, including:

1. Running on EC2 instances (Windows and Linux)
2. Running on auto-scaled EC2 instances
3. Running on ElasticBeanstalk (ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core)
4. Running in Linux Docker containers on Fargate
5. Lambda functions

I want my applications to be able to detect the environment they are running in (Development, Staging, Production) so they can load the appropriate configuration on startup, e.g. from an environment-specific folder in a Parameter Store hierarchy.

Ideally a simple API that I can call (something like `GetCurrentEnvironment()`).

What's the best way to achieve this in a way that's common to all of the above host types?

All my AWS resources are tagged with the environment name.  Is there an API  that can be called from all of the above host types that would return the tag value for the current host?

Otherwise I guess a solution would be to set an environment variable "CurrentEnvironment" or similar during creation of the host.

I guess this is a common requirement so I'd be interested to know how others do it.

Comment: You can invoke the `DescribeTags` API to get the tags attached to an EC2 resource. You can get the instance id from the instance metadata: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id. You need to attach an IAM role to the instance to get this working.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 - I know about that API, but how does it work with, say, a lambda function?  Or Elastic Beanstalk, where AFAIK I don't manage the EC2 instance?

Comment: What kind of data are you expecting from `GetCurrentEnvironment()`? Dev/stage/prod are not in-built AWS constants so I don't see how you can avoid setting it somewhere.

Comment: @Code - I know they're not built in constants and I'll have to set it somewhere, but where?  Tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tagging is the most widely supported method.

However there are more natively supported methods in each type of environment.

---

**In ElasticBeanstalk** you can set Environment Properties for the Application Environment that can be read from Web.config appSettings in the .NET Application.

**ElasticBeanstalk > [Application Name] > [Environment Name] > Configuration > Software**

Add an Application Property with a `Name` and `Value`, for example:

- Name = ReleaseEnvironment; Value = Staging
- Name = EnvironmentSecretKey; Value = SomeSecureKeyThatGainsAccessToASecureParameterStore

When Elastic Beanstalk deploys the Application to the instances, it adds this to the Web.config file in the `<appSettings>` section.

So within the Application use the following code to read the value:

```
var environmentName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReleaseEnvironment"];
```

Then you can get your environment specific properties from your Parameter Store using that value. You could also pass numerous values that way and avoid the parameter store if its more appropriate.

Other EB Deployed languages are also supported through Environment Variables: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html

---

**In Lambda**, you can set Environment Variables in the config and read them in the Lambda Container: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

---

**In ECS/Fargate**, you can pass the environment properties and read them within the container using [describe-task-definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html).

---

**In EC2**, you need to use the metadata service to read the user-data:

```
user_data=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Thanks, this is a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet for retrieving the metadata for these services. As the nature of the services itself is quite different.

For EC2 based deployments can use the [metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) or [corresponding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MetadataService.html) [sdks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html).

Autoscaled EC2 instances are no different that regular EC2 instances.

For Beanstalk, as technically a ec2 is used you can use the metadata service. However, I would rather recommend that you set the relevant items are configurations in EBS. Example say you have a application that you want to setup woth 4GB of heapspace for a Prod type of deployment and 1GB for Dev Type. You can do that during deployment.

The same goes for Lambda and containers.
Lambda does have a way to get some [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html), however, even for a lambda you will know of the config/sizing of the lambda during deployment and can use that to set relevant env variables.

So you can have the deployment scripts/jobs of these elements look at the parameter store and configure the relevant services during deployment. This will ensure that you have simpler apps and the CI/CD pipelines that you have do their share of work in setting up apps.

Tag in my opinion should be used for created metadata that you understand, what service this resource belongs to, what is its use etc.

Comment: Can I get tags from the metadata service?  Or do I need to get instance-id then e.g. invoke DescribeTags?

Comment: AFAIK, No, you need to use the Describe Tags API to be able to do that. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html. Do note that this means your EC2 instance now needs to have ec2:describe permissions